# gremlin, what is identity _() pipe

Tags: gremlin

I am using java-gremlin, and since the most examples I read about in internet are written in groovy, I supposed that identity pipe has a special meaning in groovy, but i discovered that it exists in java api, so what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

As described in TinkerPop 2.x, the `_()` turns an arbitrary object into a pipeline:

```
gremlin> x = [1,2,3]
==>1
==>2
==>3
gremlin> x._().transform{it+1}
==>2
==>3
==>4
gremlin> x = g.E.has('weight', T.gt, 0.5f).toList()
==>e[10][4-created->5]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
gremlin> x.inV
==>[StartPipe, InPipe]
==>[StartPipe, InPipe]
gremlin> x._().inV
==>v[5]
==>v[4]
```

In TinkerPop 3.x, it basically has the same meaning but we tend to refer to it more as the start of an anonymous traversal, one that is not bound to a graph instance.  You can read more about it [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/Ai8EPgk3jn0/LBbb6QDqAwAJ) in a recent post on the Gremlin Users mailing list.  Here's how it looks in 3.x:

```
gremlin> __(1,2,3)
==>1
==>2
==>3
gremlin> __(1,2,3).map{g.V(it.get()).next()}
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
```

Examples of it's usage are sprinkled throughout this section:

http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-incubating/#graph-traversal-steps

You actually see it more than you think you might as the documentation does a static import of it so that you don't actually have to use the "__()".  For example:

```
gremlin> g.V().out('knows').where(out('created'))
==>v[4]
```

is really:

```
gremlin> g.V().out('knows').where(__().out('created'))
==>v[4]
```

Finally, note that in TinkerPop 3.x, Groovy is just a "flavor" of Gremlin that introduces a small bit of syntactic sugar.  The Gremlin language in 3.x over Java 8 looks mostly identical to the Groovy flavor.

http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-incubating/#_on_gremlin_language_variants

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell you exactly about the value it brings, but it looks like it just maps to itself.

"The identity()-step (map) is an identity function which maps the current object to itself."

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#identity-step